# Printing specific section of a line when a trigger value is present

Tags: command-line, sed, awk

I'm parsing data in the following format:

```
prop1=value1:prop2=value2:prop3=value3+prop1=value4:prop2=value5
```

1. parts of the string are delimited by `+`
2. properties can appear in any order
3. the desired output is the value of prop2 from the string part where prop1 has a particular value (input)

Can I achieve this through standard unix command-line tools, or do I have to write a small C program?

Edit - for the line shown, this is the desired functionality:

```
input: value1 -> output: value2
input: value4 -> output: value5
```

Comment: Is this a multi line parse ? Could you show a couple of lines of input and required output ?

Comment: Moreover, do not expect answers to question written in a rather lousy manner.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Could you indicate the desired output?

Comment: @fedorqui Is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on devnull's answer I put together this:

```
echo $LINE | tr '+' '\n' | grep "prop1=$VALUE" | tr ':' '\n' | grep "prop2=" | cut -d= -f2
```

I'm still open to any better answers.

Comment: I'm sure a `awk` master could find an easy onliner for that :D

Comment: Great! - the power of the pipe! - though it needs `\(:\|$\)` after `$VALUE`, otherwise when `VALUE=value1` and source string has `prop1=value10`, then it yields a false positive - `$VALUE\(:\|$\)`` will get around that for even multi word property values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gawk`:

```
awk -F'+' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /value1/)
               {$i=gensub(/.*prop2=(.*)(:.*|.*$)/,"\\1","g",$i);print $i}}}' file
```

Comment: Oops! I +1'd the answer then tested further. It fails if a _"part"_ has a `prop1=your-value`, but does not have a `prop2=`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind Perl:

```
perl -053nE '
    BEGIN{ $value = shift }
    chomp;
    tr {=:}{ };
    %h = eval "qw($_)";
    say $h{prop2} if $h{prop1} eq $value
' your_file value1
```

This doesn't assume any particular order of properties, but it does assume that neither property names nor values will contain spaces. If that's not true, some more parsing would be required.

**Explanation**

- `-053` sets the record separator to the ASCII character whose octal code is `53`, namely `+`.
- `-n` means apply work on one record at a time, aliasing `$_` to the record content.
- `-E` means execute the following code with the previous switches in mind.
- The code with comments:

  ```
  perl -053nE '
      BEGIN{ $value = shift } # $value now = the command line argument
      chomp;                  # Remove the record separator (+)
      tr {=:}{ };             # Make all '=' and ':' into a space
      %h = eval "qw($_)";     # Parse the line into a hash (explained below)
      say $h{prop2} if $h{prop1} eq $value # This is your required logic
  ' your_file value1
  ```

  - The `qw()` operator takes a space-separated list and properly quotes its constituent words to create a list. When applied to the record

    ```
    prop1 value1 prop3 value3 prop2 value2
    ```

    (remember how we changed all `+` and `=` into a space), it transforms the record into a list. When this list is assigned to a hash variable `%h`, it is assumed that the hash keys are the odd numbered elements of the list and the hash values are the even numbered ones.

Comment: This works, but with a minor catch: When there is a `prop1=your_value` but no `prop2=`, it prints a blank line... Nice explanation btw ... I've got pretty minimal working knowledge of  `perl`, but I think that another feature of `-n` is that it inhibits auto-printing.

Comment: @Peter.O There is no "auto-printing" in Perl. Perl has two modes for working on a file record-by-record: `-n` (no printing) and `-p` (printing); so it's always explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will always want the first `prop1` *after* whichever `value` you pass, you could do:

```
$ perl -lne '/prop1=value1[:+].*?prop2=([^:+]+)/ && print $1' file 
value2
$ perl -lne '/prop1=value4[:+].*?prop2=([^:+]+)/ && print $1' file 
value5
```

The idea here is to match `prop1=valueN`. The `value4[:+]` makes sure that the entire value is checked, up to the next field delimiter (`:` or `+`) so that `value4` does not match `value44` for example. Then, 0 or more characters (`.*?`), followed by `prop2=` and the value of `prop2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
awk '{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        split($i, tmp, /=/)
        if(tmp[1] == "prop1") {
            printf " %s%s", "input: ",tmp[2]
        }
        if(tmp[1] == "prop2") {
            printf " %s%s", "output: ",tmp[2]
        }
     }
     print ""
}' RS='+' FS=':' file
```

**Output (with your sample input):**

```
input: value1 output: value2
input: value4 output: value5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"[:=]" -vRS='+' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if($i == "prop1") I=$(i+1); if($i == "prop2") O=$(i+1)}; printf "input: %s -> output: %s\n", I, O}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -vRS='+|\n' '
    BEGIN{ p1=":prop1="; p2=":prop2=" } 
    { if( ":"$0":" ~ p1 p1val ":" ) {
        if( match(":"$0":", p2 "[^:]+:" ) ) {
          print substr($0, RSTART+length(p2)-1, RLENGTH-length(p2)-1)
    }}}' p1val=value4
```

Pipe your string (or file) into `awk`.
The *value of prop1* is input via an arg-variable `p1val=` as shown.

Output for input: *`p1val=value1`*

```
value2
```

Output for input: *`p1val=value4`*

```
value5
```